# How can I download wine HQ?

Tags: software-installation, wine, download

I have a desperate problem.  I really need wineHQ, and I can't download or install.   I can download other apps, but wineHQ won't download.  I can't install it by running `sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable` ; it says, "unable to locate package".  I have ubuntu 21.10.  I am trying to download it from https://wiki.winehq.org/Download .  I am trying to get the ubuntu version of it.   I have a working internet connection because I download other apps and install all the time.  I have dowloaded and installed several apps since I first ran into this problem.  I also can browser the web without any problems.  I also downloaded some other little things from the wineHQ site, I just can't get the app itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the repository before executing the `apt` command.

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 
wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key
sudo apt-key add winehq.key
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ impish main' 
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
```

Comment: Excellent!!! It worked!!!!!  Thanks!!!!  You don't know how badly I needed wine!  Thanks!!!  I had tried a similar list of commands from other people, but yours is the only one that worked!

Answer (score 2):

The Debian package is simply called "wine", not "winehq"

https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/wine